# Spring: default value is always overriding when using context:?

Tags: java, spring

If I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:${PropertiesFile}" ignore-unresolvable="false" ignore-resource-not-found="false" />

    <bean id="SpringMailSender" class="${MailSenderClass:org.mypackage.MockJavaMailSenderImpl}">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And the property file contains:

```
MailSenderClass=org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl
```

I would expect the `org.mypackage.MockJavaMailSenderImpl` class to not be used but it always is. I don't normally see this behaviour and the defaults work as expected. I am having trouble trying to track down what is going on here. I am working around this by removing the default value and ensuring my property files all specify this property.

Can anyone help explain why it is behaving this way and how to get the defaulting to work as I would expect in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help since I only want one bean and having multiple instances of the bean of the wrong class isn't going to improve the situation. Very simply if I do not specify the override it uses what is in the property file: which is what it should have been doing in the first place.

Comment: I don't think you understand the situation.

Comment: Your properties file itself is a placeholder location right - can you try not using a placeholder and see if it works consistently based off the entry in the file.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with context itself since org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer doesn't produce the same sort of problems.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue and the reason for me was that I had another `<context:property-placeholder` defined elsewhere configured with `ignore-unresolvable="true"` which was trying to inject the property without success, resulting in having the default value.